# jQuery/CSS positioning on my first project an etch a sketch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I'm currently learning CSS, jQuery, Javascript and have made an etch-a-sketch as a first project. I've managed to put a few features in that see to work without any issues, however with the snake feature I have an issue where if you hole the mouse of a square it seems to move to the bottom of the grid and continue to do so, I think it is due to the way the grid is generated or the floating of the divs but I can't work it out. Can someone suggest any way to fix the issue? I would really appreciate it you let me know if you see anything in the code that could be improved as I'm just at the beginning of my learning journey!

The project is viewable here http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/timmknight/etch-a-sketch/blob/master/index.html

and the files are on my github at https://github.com/timmknight/etch-a-sketch

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I can't see any snake featrures in the post. Please add the relevant code to the post.

Comment: @Teemu - there's a big button saying 'Snake'!?

Comment: @DeeMac In the post? It seems I really need glasses, I can't see that button ; ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to lie in the last line of this function:

```
function trail(){
  clearGrid()
  $('.square').css("background-color", "#CFCFCF")
  $('.square').hover(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "#CFCFCF")
    $(this).fadeToggle("slow") // this line is the issue
  });
}
```

fadeToggle is reducing the opacity of the target overtime. Once the opacity hits 0 the target's display is set to "none". So in a grid of 20x20 instead of showing 400 elements it shows 399 everytime your hover causes an element to hide. So to summarize, nothing is moving to the bottom, your hover is causing all the elements to shift to the left in the grid leaving an empty space at the end.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I managed to fix the issue after you explained it by changing it to fadeTo and then using a callback.